# Trimming my panel dataset - filtering out observations meeting criterion if preceding ID meets the complementary criterion

Tags: stata, panel-data

I am working with a dataset that includes 118,979 observations over 9 wide variables in **Stata** 16.0. The most prominent variable is whether a company-observation over multiple dates reports either "GPS" or "EPS". These companies can report both a "GPS" observation in a datapoint, as well as an "EPS" observation in the following datapoint. Please refer to the data overview below for further visualisation.

Datasample:

```
clear
input str8 cusip8 str16 cname str4 measure double actual long anndats_act float(fyear tanalyst meanforcast UE)
"87482X10" "TALMER BANCORP"   "EPS"   1.21 20118 2014  29   .8686207     .3930131
"87482X10" "TALMER BANCORP"   "GPS"   1.02 20479 2015  34   .8576471     .1893004
```

I need to drop the GPS observations (over multiple dates) once an identifier (being cusip8 in the table above) has reported an EPS over multiple dates. That is, if a company has reported GPS as well as EPS in e.g. January 1st, 2010, I want to drop the GPS observation such that the EPS is kept.
If a company only reports a GPS, and does not report an EPS during a given date, I want to keep the GPS observation in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (adjust your variable names as required):

```
. clear

. input str10(company_id measure) month day year

     company_id measure month day year
  1. "Company A" "EPS" 1 1 2010
  2. "Company A" "GPS" 1 1 2010 
  3. "Company A" "GPS" 1 1 2010
  4. "Company A" "GPS" 1 2 2010
  5. "Company B" "EPS" 1 2 2010
  6. "Company B" "GPS" 1 1 2010
  7. "Company C" "GPS" 1 4 2010
  8. "Company C" "EPS" 1 4 2010
  9. end

. 
. gen date = mdy(month,day,year)

. format date %d

. drop month day year

. 
. sort company_id date measure

. 
. gen both = 0

. by company_id date: replace both = 1 if measure[1] == "EPS" & measure[2] == "GPS"
(5 real changes made)

. 
. list, sepby(company_id)

     +----------------------------------------+
     | company~d   measure        date   both |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. | Company A       EPS   01jan2010      1 |
  2. | Company A       GPS   01jan2010      1 |
  3. | Company A       GPS   01jan2010      1 |
  4. | Company A       GPS   02jan2010      0 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  5. | Company B       GPS   01jan2010      0 |
  6. | Company B       EPS   02jan2010      0 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  7. | Company C       EPS   04jan2010      1 |
  8. | Company C       GPS   04jan2010      1 |
     +----------------------------------------+

. 
. drop if measure == "GPS" & both == 1
(3 observations deleted)

. 
. list, sepby(company_id)

     +----------------------------------------+
     | company~d   measure        date   both |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. | Company A       EPS   01jan2010      1 |
  2. | Company A       GPS   02jan2010      0 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  3. | Company B       GPS   01jan2010      0 |
  4. | Company B       EPS   02jan2010      0 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  5. | Company C       EPS   04jan2010      1 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```